# Injecting a shadow dom to a page that has keybindings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I inject a textarea at the top-left of the page. If I inject it without Shadow DOM, I can write anything I want. However, if I use Shadow DOM, some keys won't work because Yahoo (as an example) has bound the "S" key to focus on the search bar. So when a user tries to write "S" in my textarea, it doesn't work, it focuses on yahoo's search bar. Is there any solution for this?

I tried to add
preventDefault() and stopPropogation() on keyup, keydown, input events but didn't work

[image: shadow dom]

Comment: Try `elem.contentEditable = true` on the host element.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much @wOxxOm ! Is there any technical reading/docs I can read, why this fixes the issue?

Comment: It marks the element as a text input field.